# Codeigniter function "from_label()" is giving error

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I sent you guys a screenshot of error, the form is working properly the only issue is in "`from_label()`" if I comment it the input field is working properly without any error

[image: wrror]

```
<?php $attributes = array('id' => 'login_form','class' => 'form_horizontal'); ?>

<?php echo form_open($login_user, $attributes); ?>

<div class="from-group">

    <?php echo from_label(); ?>
    <?php echo from_input(); ?>

</div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
<?php echo from_label(); ?>   
            ^^
<?php echo from_input(); ?>
            ^^
```

to

```
<?php echo form_label(); ?>
<?php echo form_input(); ?>
```

---

**Reference**

1. [`form_label([$label_text = ''[, $id = ''[, $attributes =
   array()]]])`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_label)
2. [`form_input([$data = ''[, $value = ''[, $extra = '']]])`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_input)

---

**FYI:**

1. `form_label()` need the first argument as run smoothly. `echo
   form_label('What is your Name');` (even with `form-input`)
2. Even your class `from-group` should be `form-group`